# CSS for displaying empty div

Tags: css, jsf

I have a JSF template with three important components:
**template.xhtml:**

```
<div class="leftStripe">
  <ui:insert name="leftStripe"></ui:insert>
</div>
<div class="mainStripe">
  <ui:insert name="mainStripe"></ui:insert>                
</div>
<div class="rightStripe">
  <ui:insert name="rightStripe"></ui:insert>
</div>
```

**style.css:**

```
.mainStripe{width:70%; float:left; margin: auto; min-height: 100%;}
.leftStripe{width:15%; float:left; height:100%;}
.rightStripe{width:14%; float:right; height:100%;}
```

**index.xhtml:**

```
<ui:composition template="resources/templates/template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="mainStripe">
    /* something useful... notice there's no leftStripe */
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**someOtherFile.xhtml:**

```
<ui:composition template="resources/templates/template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="leftStripe">
    /* something useful */
  </ui:define>
  <ui:define name="mainStripe">
    /* something useful */
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The **mainStripe** always has some content. The **leftStripe** might have something in it, but doesn't have to (e.g. in the **index.xhtml**). But even if it's empty, I want it to be on the page and to "occupy" the leftmost 15% of the page, so the **mainStripe** could be positioned in the center.
Unfortunately, the **leftStripe** doesn't show when it's empty.
It will be shown (even in **index.xhtml**) if I put the fixed height (e.g. 100px) instead of 100%, but I would really like it to fill the whole height of the page. Is there any way to do that?
I have tried the following:

```
.leftStripe{width:15%; float:left; height:100%;}
.leftStripe:empty{height:100px;}
```

...but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `leftStripe` is Empty you could try to print a `&nbsp;` so it has at least a space as content.

EDIT: Since the clarification. Add the `&nbsp;` to the template, so if it's not overwritten, it contains only the space, and when it's overwritten, you probably have content.

SO:

template.xhtml:

```
<div class="leftStripe">
  <ui:insert name="leftStripe">&nbsp;</ui:insert>
</div>
<div class="mainStripe">
  <ui:insert name="mainStripe">&nbsp;</ui:insert>                
</div>
<div class="rightStripe">
  <ui:insert name="rightStripe">&nbsp;</ui:insert>
</div>
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Now I feel like an idiot for not being able (actually, for being too lazy) to figure this out myself :). Thanks!

Comment: Well i never used xhtml (I already used html5), so I tried to setup your config and tried nbsp and it worked ;-)